# ActiveRecord has_many association null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 models that are interacting:

- `Sessions`
- Each `Session` has multiple `SessionPlayer`s
- Each `SessionPlayer` belongs to `Player`

On the associated Session index, I am trying to display the list of session players for a given session, and each session player's player name -- `session_player.player.name`. Running the Rails page provides me with the proper data, but during testing I am having an issue.

In the index.html.erb page I am using the following loop:

```
<% @sessions.each do |session| %>
  <% session.session_player.each do |player| %>
      <div><%= player.player.name %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When the code is executed during test, it is getting a null exception on `player.player`, however I can debug it and it has a value set up properly for `player.player_id` leading me to believe there is something wrong with my model code or some strange caching going on during the test.

`Session` model

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_player
  has_many :player,  through: :session_player
end
```

`SessionPlayer` model

```
class SessionPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :session
end
```

`Player` model

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_player
  has_many :session, through: :session_player
end
```

The test and fixture data are both boilerplate created via RubyMine (as were the controllers and models), but I can post those if need be.

Comment: first of all try changing: `has_many :session_players`

Comment: and second: `session.session_players.each`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you used `session_player`, but it should be `session_players`, use this line instead

```
<% session.session_players.each do |player| %>
```

And in your model, since you are using `has_many`, you should use pluralized form of model name

```
has_many :session_players
```